# NumberFormatException probably the BigDecimalInvalid long: "1,00" android-sdk-paypal

Tags: android, paypal, bigdecimal, number-formatting

I have this error when I try to convert a double to bigdecimal

```
BigDecimal  bb = new BigDecimal(""+total);
                                Log.i("","voila le bigdecimal : "+bb);

                                PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(
                                        new BigDecimal(""+total), currency,
                                        "MyApp");
```

knowing that I use that locale in all activities

```
        Locale locale = new Locale("fr_FR"); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

and when I don't use this locale (english is the default one), I don't have the problem

I think it might be a bug in paypal android sdk

but do you have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was reported in our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/34), and a fix was deployed this week.  Please download the latest sdk and let us know if this fixes your issue.